# AttributeError: module 'django.db.migrations' has no attribute 'RunPython'

Tags: python, django

I get this error whenever I try running my server, migrating, or running any Django commands. All my previous Django projects also show the same error, but they were working fine before. I tried updating Django, but it's still showing the same error.

This is the error I am getting.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1010, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 947, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 115, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 123, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\apps.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .checks import check_models_permissions, check_user_model
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\checks.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .management import _get_builtin_permissions
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.management import create_contenttypes
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\management\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    class RenameContentType(migrations.RunPython):
AttributeError: module 'django.db.migrations' has no attribute 'RunPython'
```

Comment: try removing all the files in the the migration folder, except for __init__.py and also locate your databasefile: db.sqlite3 and delete it. Then run makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: I am having same issue, suggested solution above did not work for me. @Snehal Adbol, did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all the files in migration and re-run this command:

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Your Django installation is corrupted.

I had this happen when I ran a rogue `rm -rf` command to remove all contents of folders named "migrations".  This went into my virtual environment and deleted the contents of the Django library's internal "migrations" module.

Re-creating your virtualenv should solve this.